# Text in a fixed height/width card with overflow carousel to display remaining content

Tags: css, pagination, overflow, carousel

I have a card with fixed height and width inside which I have to populate dynamic content. The content for this will be a big list of {key, value} in simple string format. I have to display each key, value pair with a line break.

1. Add one line break after every key-value pair.
2. If the list overflows the card height, add a next button at the bottom and when clicked, display the remaining text.

Ex: if suppose my card can accommodate 3 key/value pairs and if there are 9 entries then I have to show 3 pages of text with next/prev buttons.

[image: page 1 of overflowing text]
[image: page 2 of overflowing text]

I guess with overflow property we can identify and add a scroll, but how do I do this pagination? Is there any property like column-count or something that can help? I am not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that CSS has the logics to scroll a certain amount of the page after you click the NEXT or PREV button. You need to use a bit of Javascript to attain the functionality.

For the 'NEXT' button you should use the code:

```
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
   let cardHt = card.offsetHeight;//Calculate the height of the card
   card.scrollY(cardHt+'px');//Scroll down the height of the card
});
```

Similarily, for the 'PREV' Button you need to use:

```
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let cardHt = card.offsetHeight;//Calculate the height of the card
    card.scrollY(-cardHt+'px');//Scroll up the height of the card
});
```

Comment: Thanks man. It gave me an idea, although I did use scrollTop to navigate back and forth. But another tricky part here, I need to make it scroll horizontally. I need to be able to make the overflow horizontally beyond the width :)

Comment: I am glad that it helped you anyways! ;-) @vp310